# How to convert variables written as a text (or in a mySQL text field) in PHP variables?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm saving part of my variables in MySQL fields instead of files
How can I recover it of a part of new PHP file?
And using a similar functions like **include()** but for variables.

As an idea of theoretical code:

```html
<?php
$var = '$nom = "NOMBRE";
 $cognom = "APELLIDO";
  ';

// something like this but for variable
include ($var);

echo $nom;
echo $cognom;

// Result: NOMBRE APELLIDO
?>
```

Comment: Use database to store values not code.

Comment: Why would you want to take a performance hit by doing it this way? Not trying to be a smartalek, just curious to see if there is a legit reason to go so far outside the box.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`eval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) to execute a string as PHP code. Simply change:

```
include ($var);
```

to

```
eval($var);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very bad approach and application design to store code in the database.

Now, it might looks much easier to rapidly develop the application however in the future you will face to huge obstacles to do even simple changes in the app and its data.

Imagine that you will have a table of users and you will need to fine all users with the same last name... In well structured database you will simply run code like:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE surname 'Doe';
```

However if the database will keep the code with variables holding the variable  `$name="John";$surname="Doe";` it will be much more tricky to search correct substring not speaking about the issues with indexing, performance and weird logic at all.

```
SELECT * FROM codes WHERE code LIKE <magic to find the correct variable and it's value>;
```

Not speaking about sorting, calculations, agregations and other useful functionality providing us the database.

So store atomic values in well structured database table such id, name, surname, nick, etc.

Comment: Thank you. I'll do that.